Second Order System of Differential Equations Solution
We have the second order system (the parameters are real)
$$\tag 1 y''(t) = \omega z'(t)$$
$$\tag 2 z''[t] = w \left( \dfrac{e}{b} - y'(t) \right)$$
The solution to this system is
$$y(t) = c_1 \cos(\omega t) + c_2 \sin(\omega t) + \left(\dfrac{e}{b}\right) t + c_3$$
$$z(t) = -c_1 \sin(\omega t) + c_2 \cos(\omega t) + c_4$$
One solution approach is to take the derivative of the $(1)$, substitute $(2)$ into $(1)$ and solve as
  DSolve[y'''[t] == w  (w (e/b - y'[t])), y, t]

This produces the correct result for $y(t)$ and it is straightforward to find $z(t)$ and it matches the hand solution above.
However, when I try using the second order equations as-is, I get expressions that I cannot figure out how to (full)simplify to get the same result.
  DSolve[{y''[t] == w  z[t], z''[t] == w (e/b - y'[t])}, {y, z}, t]

Is there any way to get the second solution to match the above?

Your code does not match your latex. Is this what you meant?
sol=DSolve[{y''[t]==w  z'[t],z''[t]==w (e/b-y'[t])},{y[t],z[t]},t];
Expand[%]



I am not following your comment, what do you mean it does not match? I converted the second second order system into a third order to do the first solution - is that what you are talking about?

@Moo  In your code you typed y''[t] == w  z[t], but in your latex eq(1) you type  y''[t] == w  z'[t],  these are not the same.  Your Latex hasz'and your code does not have derivative onz`

Ah! Now I see what you meant - I should just delete this question because that is a user error. Thanks!
